# How to load music from SD card / Music+Video hub in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing Windows Phone music app that aims to play music and let the user enjoy features that aren't available in Music+Video app (default app). I want to import the current available music in the device or at least be able to import music to the app easily from pc.

How can I achieve this ? I searched for that but I didn't anything that can help , although I saw this feature in other apps available in the store now.

Answer (score 3):

**MediaLibrary**

If you want to access the music already detected by the phone (both on the device memory and SD card), then use the `MediaLibrary` to access all the tracks...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd231914.aspx

http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/28/31-days-of-mango-day-28-media-library/

**ExternalStorage**

If you want to access the SD card, then you'll have to use `ExternalStorage` API...

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-local-storage-windows

**BackgroundAudioPlayer**

And if you're serious about making a music player, you will have to also use the `BackgroundAudioPlayer` which allows music to keep playing even when your app is not running...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx